How to make a brush bend against the paper using Hair system?
I managed to create hair in the shape of a pointy tip using the edit mode, but when I try to do the brush bending , it doesn't keep its shape.
I need it to be rigid when I do the simulation, giving a bent curve.
I didn't find any tutorial about this on YouTube, but I saw shorts from people who did it.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Depending on what kind of appearance you need, I might not use a particle system here, and just use a big soft body with a streaked bump texture instead

is this for animation or a still image?
